# Qual o problema? Me retorna apenas undefined quando tento acessar especificamente a temp

Tags: javascript, json, api

```
var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest()
var bot = document.querySelector(".botao");
bot.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log('buscando...')

    xhr.open("GET","https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=3450554&appid=6b8661b06c381528f71386ee3a01ff53&units=metric")
    xhr.send();
})



xhr.addEventListener("load",function(){

var resposta= xhr.responseText;
var respostajson= JSON.parse(resposta)
console.log(respostajson)

console.log(respostajson["main.temp"])


});
```

Comment: Faz assim `console.log(respostajson["main"]["temp"])`

Answer (score 3):

Você está tentando acessar uma propriedade dentro de um objeto então a sintaxe que utilizou não está correta, o correto utilizando a notação de **colchetes** seria `["main"]["temp"]`, ou seja, em cada par de colchetes uma propriedade do objeto como comentado pelo **Augusto Vasques**, eu particularmente não gosto de utilizar essa notação, prefiro acessar propriedades de objetos com o sinal de **ponto (.)** por deixar o código mais legível.

Imagina se tivesse que acessar uma propriedade no índice **0** por exemplo a sintaxe ficaria assim: `respostajson["main"][0]["temp"]`, para mim isso fica estranho e mais confuso do que a notação por ponto: `respostajson.main[0].temp`

Então pode fazer como comentado utilizando colchetes ou como no exemplo abaixo:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var bot = document.querySelector(".botao");

bot.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log('buscando...')

  xhr.open("GET", "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=3450554&appid=6b8661b06c381528f71386ee3a01ff53&units=metric")
  xhr.send();
})

xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var resposta = xhr.responseText;
  var respostajson = JSON.parse(resposta);
  
  console.log(respostajson)
  console.log(respostajson.main.temp)
});
```

```html
<button class="botao">Buscar</button>
```